# Could a super volcano cause ragnarok like events?

Tags: weather, volcanoes, ragnarok

For the world I am creating I am trying to have an event like a super volcano explosion in its past. Generations of oral storytelling have resulted in the Norse mythology of Ragnarok making its way to earth.

Could events following the super volcano reflect a Ragnarok like timeline? For example, a "Great Winter" lasting three years, sun and moon disappearing from view as if swallowed by great wolves, and a massive fire. This would be followed by a "rebirth" of great bounty and prosperity.

Comment: A ragnarok-like timeline? Like, submerging the world in water after a terrible battle? Could we have some specifics on what that means in an edit on your post?

Comment: Look up the Permian-Triassic extinction, AKA the Great Dying".  High on the list of possible causes is a large volcanic event that just happened to occur beneath large coal beds.

Comment: If you're willing to define "extreme weather" then I'm willing to vote to reopen this. Your description of Ragnarok seems specific enough now.

Comment: Extreme weather doesn't influece the chances of having a supervolcano. Besides this, now your question sound more clear.

Comment: I have removed the issue of weather as there seems to be a consensus that it wouldn't influence this event and is only clouding (pun intended!) the question. Thanks all for the feedback!

Comment: Locally in a small village somewhere or globally?

Comment: @Raditz_35, anything between continent and globe would work. Enough to raise extinction concerns for dominant and intelligent species.

Comment: Quite possible.   The Krakatoa eruption ejected aproximately 6 cubic miles of rock into the Earth's atmosphere which resulted in record cold winters and blizzards around the world for the following four years.   By comparison, the last eruption of the Yellowstone Caldera Supervolcano is believed to have ejected 240 cubic miles of rock into the Earth's atmosphere.  A more winter like effect would certainly be possible if the population were closer when the ash falls.  If Krakatoa happened in Los Angeles, the explosion would be heard in New York City for a comparison of what "close" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes and no.** A volcanic eruption can cause all three of the things you specified, but I'm not certain it can cause *all of them at the same time*.

---

> A "Great Winter" lasting three years

The eruption of Mount Tambora in 1815, one of the largest eruptions in recorded history, led to the "Year Without A Summer", in which global temperatures were about 2-3 degrees Celsius lower than normal, rivers froze over, and crops failed in many places. An even larger eruption could easily extend that cold snap to three years [or even more](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/33438/32016).

> Sun and moon disappearing from view as if swallowed by great wolves

A supervolcano can easily eject enough ash into the atmosphere to block out the sun (and by extension, the moon), albeit temporarily. This is, in fact, what would cause your "Great Winter". The more ash is ejected, the longer and harsher your Great Winter is going to be. I don't know how long the sun and moon would actually be blocked for, however.

> A massive fire

A nice big lava flow will set everything in its vicinity on fire. However, an eruption of this size is more likely to cause a *pyroclastic flow*, a huge wave of superheated air and rock travelling at supersonic speeds. Pyroclastic flows don't set things on fire, they either completely destroy them or bury them under several feet of ash (as famously happened to Pompeii).

---

Of course, it's your story. You can always handwave it to say that all three of these things *did* happen. The important part for you is that they *can* happen.